# Add Interaction.Behavior programmatically

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a textbox for Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight) that behaves like a normal TextBox with a special behaviour.
The behavior being that the ViewModel is updated as soon as the user types and not when the TextBox loses focus.
This is something I have now and is working...

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Email,Mode=TwoWay}" InputScope="EmailNameOrAddress">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <helpers:UpdateTextBindingOnPropertyChanged />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

I would like to create a FastTextbox subclass of textbox that has this behavior by default.
How can I add this behaviour programmatically?

I tried this :

```
public class FastTextbox:System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
{
    public FastTextbox()
    {
        BehaviorCollection Behaviors= Interaction.GetBehaviors(this);
        Behaviors.Add(new UpdateTextBindingOnPropertyChanged());
    }
}
```

But I get an error in my behaviour.
The behavior I use uses the following code to determine it's expression (which fails).

```
protected override void OnAttached()
{
    base.OnAttached();

    // expression gets null here :(
    _expression = AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    AssociatedObject.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
}
```

How should I do this?

Comment: It seems to me or are you missing InitializeComponent in TextBox constructor?

Comment: @verdesrobert: (Disclaimer: I don't program for WP7/8 but assuming that their Silverlight Framework offers an API similar to the desktop version) `InitializeComponent` is only needed for UserControls.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: as long as you have not set any binding to your `FastTextbox.Text` property the `GetBindingExpression` will return null. This is absolutely correct behavior. There is no binding expression yet.

[Edit]
One solution could be: maybe there is an override for OnTextChanged or OnTextPropertyChanged and you can call the `GetBindingExpression` method there.

[Edit2]
Can you use `Text="{Binding Path=Email, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`? The need for a `FastTextbox` would cease.

Answer (score 1):

The actual solution was quite simple :)

```
    public FastTextbox()
    {
        TextChanged += OnTextBoxTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox senderText = (TextBox)sender;
        BindingExpression bindingExp = senderText.GetBindingExpression(TextProperty);
        bindingExp.UpdateSource();
    }
```